# Unexpected need to assert Collection?.Method(...) in some but not all cases of parameters

Tags: c#, mongodb

***NB.** The question **is not** about what null reference protector operator (X?.Y) means. I'm aware the title is a bit cryptical but I haven't figure out a better way to formulate it. Sorry.*

I'm using [FindOneAndReplaceAsync(...)](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_FindOneAndReplaceAsync__1.htm) and according to it, the default for the options is `null`.

```
  await Things.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(
    x => x.Id == target.Id, replacement, null, token);
```

Passing an explicit `null` works just as expected. However, when I create an instance of [FindOneAndReplaceOptions](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FindOneAndReplaceOptions_1.htm), the compiler suddently worries about the object I'm performing my search on being undefined.

```
FindOneAndReplaceOptions<Thing> options = new FindOneAndReplaceOptions<Thing>();
await Things.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(
  x => x.Id == target.Id, replacement, options, token);
```

In order to compile I have to assert `Things` to be non-null.

```
FindOneAndReplaceOptions<Thing> options = new FindOneAndReplaceOptions<Thing>();
await Things?.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(
  x => x.Id == target.Id, replacement, options, token);
```

While I understand the suggestion, I can't grasp why the complaint comes up only when an instance of options object is passed. I checked that I'm not stumbling on an overload. The same phenomenon comes up even if there's no actual instance passed, like so.

```
FindOneAndReplaceOptions<Thing> options = null;
await Things?.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(
  x => x.Id == target.Id, replacement, options, token);
```

What's going on here? I feel confused...

Comment: Just F12 both of those methods. I'm betting the first one is an extension method, and the second one isn't

Comment: @canton7 Good eyes. Although, to be honest, your answer below brings in much more clarity on the subject than the cryptic comment. Let it stay, though. It might be fun for the next person to figure what on Earth you refer to. (BTW, I was there has been several comments to this question, deleted now, were those yours?)

Comment: That comment was just based on the knowledge that extension methods can be called on a `null` receiver, so that was the obvious explanation for why one call gave a nullable warning and the other didn't. The rest of the puzzle was why one call was resolving to an instance method and the other to an extension method, and that finally lead to my answer. It's worth noting that your very first statement "*I'm using FindOneAndReplaceAsync(...)*" is wrong -- that doc is for the wrong overload. If you'd have F12'd the method and got the docs for the actual overload, it might have been clearer :)

Comment: Yeah those were mine -- one turned out to be wrong, the other was superceded by my full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fun. If you whittle it down to a minimal reproducer, you get this:

```
#nullable enable

public class C
{
    public void M(IMongoCollection<string>? collection)
    {
        // No warning
        collection.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(null);
    }
    
    public void N(IMongoCollection<string>? collection)
    {
        // Warning
        collection.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(new FindOneAndReplaceOptions<string>());
    }
}

#nullable disable

public interface IMongoCollection<TDocument>
{
    Task FindOneAndReplaceAsync<TProjection>(FindOneAndReplaceOptions<TDocument, TProjection> options = null);
}

public static class MongoCollectionExtensions
{
    public static Task FindOneAndReplaceAsync<TDocument>(
        this IMongoCollection<TDocument> doc,
        FindOneAndReplaceOptions<TDocument, TDocument> options = null) => Task.CompletedTask;
}

public class FindOneAndReplaceOptions<TDocument, TProjection>
{
}

public class FindOneAndReplaceOptions<TDocument> : FindOneAndReplaceOptions<TDocument, TDocument>
{
}
```

See it on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

This really boils down to 3 things:

1. Overload resolution prefers instance methods to extension methods.
2. You can call extension methods on a `null` receiver, but not instance methods.
3. MongoDB doesn't have nullability annotations

Notice that the signature of `IMongoCollection<TDocument>.FindOneAndReplaceAsync<TProjection>(...)` (which is the simplified version of [this MongoDB method](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_FindOneAndReplaceAsync__1.htm)) has that `TProjection` type parameter, which links to the `FindOneAndReplaceOptions<TDocument, TProjection>` parameter.

If you pass in `null` as the value of `options`, the compiler has no way of inferring what that `TProjection` type parameter is, so overload resolution fails, and it moves onto the extension methods.

That `FindOneAndReplaceAsync` extension method (which is the simplified version of [this MongoDB method](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_FindOneAndReplaceAsync__1_3.htm)) doesn't have a `TProjection` type parameter, and its `options` parameter has type `FindOneAndReplaceOptions<TDocument, TDocument>`).

This means that the compiler has all of the information it needs to infer all type parameters, even if you pass in `null` as the value of `options`.

When you call `collection.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(null)`, therefore, the compiler can't bind to the instance method (as it can't infer `TProjection`), and has to bind to the extension method.

Since MongoDB doesn't have nullability annotations, the compiler simply doesn't know whether a `null` value for the `doc` parameter is allowed or not, so it assumes that it is allowed. Therefore, there's no nullability warning.

However, when you pass in an instance of `FindOneAndReplaceOptions<TDocument>` (which inherits from `FindOneAndReplaceOptions<TDocument, TDocument>`, the compiler has enough information to infer the type of `TProjection`: it's the same as `TDocument`! So it can now bind to the instance method, and calling an instance method on something which could be `null` merits a warning.

Comment: It was weird, right? And I refer to *weird* as in *amusingly and unexpectedly nerdy* in a positive sense. First time I've stumbled upon such a combination of predispositions in 15 years. And it has actually nothing to do with MongoDb as such, right?

Comment: Well, it came about because of the specific overloads provided by MongoDB (and the fact that one's an extension method and one's an instance method), and the fact that your have nullable reference types enabled and MongoDB doesn't. I thought it was going to be some fun around `FilterDefinition` have an implicit conversion from `Expression<T>`, and someone else being chosen in favour of that, at first, it turned out to be a nice, simple generic type inference issue

Comment: It definitely did answer my question and very well too. I had both upvoted and accepted it as the correct answer. Doesn't it show as so for you? You most certainly deserve both - this was one of the better replies I've seen on SO, to be honest.